# Proving that there are infinitely many prime numbers of the form $4k+3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

[image]

Anyone wanna help me solve this one? Been at it for a little bit but haven't really gotten anywhere..

Comment: The *answer* lies in the question *itself*, you can't get a number of form $4p_1p_2 \cdots p_m-1$ with just numbers of form $k \equiv 1(\mod 4)$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that there were finitely many prime numbers of the form $4k+3$; call them $p_1,\ldots,p_m$. Let
$$N=4p_1\cdots p_m-1.$$
Then $N\equiv 3\bmod 4$. What can you say about the prime divisors of a number that is $3\bmod 4$?

Comment: Wouldn't you just say that it leaves a remainder of 1, which is a prime number as well? Sorry, I'm a little lost, and we haven't really used the mod idea yet, although I'm aware of what it is.

Comment: @Miguel: $N \equiv 3(\mod 4)$ is just that the number $N$ is of form $4k+3$, or when you say $a \equiv b(\mod n)$, it means when $a$ is divided by $n$, it leaves a remainder $b$.

Comment: @Miguel: No, a number of the form $4r-1$ leaves a remainder of $3$ when you divide it by $4$ (it's easy to see this if you rewrite $4r-1$ as $4(r-1)+3$). Also, $1$ is not a prime number. At any rate, what you need to know is that 
$$\bullet\;\text{if $a\equiv b\bmod 4$ and $c\equiv d\bmod 4$,  then $ac\equiv bd\bmod 4$}\hspace{0.33in}\\
\bullet\;\text{any prime number $q$ satisfies exactly one of the following:}\\
\quad  \circ q\equiv 1\bmod 4\hspace{3in}\\
\quad  \circ q\equiv 3\bmod 4\hspace{3in}\\
\quad \circ q=2\hphantom{{}\bmod 4}\hspace{3in} $$

Comment: Thus, if I take any collection of numbers each of which is equivalent to $1\bmod 4$, then their product must also be $1\bmod 4$. Since $N\equiv 3\bmod 4$, what does that tell you about at least one of the prime divisors of $N$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are finitely many primes $p_1, \dots, p_k$ of the form $4n + 3$. Let $m = 4p_1 \dots p_k -1$.  Note that $m \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, and in particular, $m$ is odd so $2 \nmid m$.  Thus all primes dividing $m$ have to be of the form $4n + 1$, but that implies $m \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, a contradiction.